# Java: Compare two ArrayLists which containing inner ArrayLists

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, arraylist, comparison

I've got two ArrayList which contains again ArrayLists of type Hardware:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Hardware>> list1;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Hardware>> list2;
```

The class Hardware contains of an ElementType enumeration, which determine the type of Hardware:

```
enum ElementType{
    Microcontroller;
    Core;
    Memory;
    Sensor;
    Pin;
    Port;
}
```

Example for list1, which contains 3 ArrayList of type Hardware:

```
[Microcontroller, Memory]
[Port]
[Pin]
```

Example for list2, which contains 6 ArrayList of type Hardware:

```
[Microcontroller, Memory]
[Microcontroller, Memory]
[Microcontroller, Port]
[Microcontroller, Core]
[Sensor]
[Pin]
```

Now I want to check if all ArrayList of list 1 are contained in list2 and have the same order:

This would be valid:

```
[Microcontroller, Memory, Core] == [Microcontroller, Memory, Core]
```

while this would have not the same order and therefore invalid:

```
[Microcontroller, Memory, Core] == [Microcontroller, Core, Memory]
```

At the end, I need to know if all ArrayList of list1 are also in the same order in list2 and which one of list2 are it.

I'm struggeling with this for a while, as I don't know how to use helper methods of Collection for this and my first idea of using loops was pretty poor hasn't helped me:

```
private void check() {
    for (ArrayList<Hardware> listOf1 : list1) {
        for (Hardware abstHw : listOf1) {
            System.out.println(abstHw);
                    ????????????
        }
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help me with this or give me some handy tips?

Cheers,
Phil

------------------Edit---------------

Just to clarify:

The Hardware instances of list1 and list2 are not the same! They can only be compared through the ElementType.

Answer (score 0):

You know, what you want is actually pretty simple:

```
private void check() {
    return list2.containsAll(list1);
}
```

In fact, you probably don't need a separate method, if it's this simple.

Comment: This looks simple but its not. The use has an ArrayList of ArrayList and for comparison you need to loop over and then call containsAll

Comment: @GV You are wrong. The sub-array lists are compared with `equals` by `containsAll`, which is what is wanted.

Comment: Also it would compare the containing objects, which are instances of HardwareElement. Both Lists contains different objects, only the ElementType can be the same

Answer (score -1):

You could use `List#retainAll()` for this:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Hardware>> list1;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Hardware>> list2;
list2.retainAll(list1);
```

The list of elements in the intersection (`list2` after doing `List#retainAll()`) is what you are looking for. If two inner-lists have the same objects, but not in the same order, it won't be considered the same, so you don't have explicitly worry about that.

NOTE: `List#retainAll()` will modify the actual `list1` object. If you need to preserve it, make a copy before doing this.

Comment: See comments on my answer.

Comment: The objects are not the same. They just can be compared through their ElementType (Enum).

Comment: @ph09 Would it be possible to override `equals` in `Hardware`?

Comment: Unfortunately this classes are generated by EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework) and I would like to avoid changing them. How should the equal method work like?